# Apollo mini-bike? For real?

Tags: apollo-program, lunar-rover

NASA considered motorcycle style transportation for use on Lunar missions. Apparently, it didn’t make the cut, despite the fact it “got air” in a 1/6-G test run:

[image]

Fig. 4: Test of an Apollo Motorbike prototype flying in the former NASA KC-135 aircraft in parabolic curves to reproduce a 1/6 gravity environment in short 20-second bursts.
IAC-18,A5,1,12,x47143 69 th International Astronautical Congress (IAC),

According to https://www.americaspace.com/2012/04/06/how-nasa-didnt-drive-on-the-moon consideration was also given to bicycles and a two-seater quadricycle. The minibike (pictured above)

> was under development in 1969 for use on Apollo 15. It was a backup
> method in case the Lunar Roving Vehicle, the LRV colloquially known as
> the Moon Buggy, wasn’t ready in time for the mission’s launch. There
> was some talk about the mini bikes incorporated into later Apollo
> missions as well.

Was the Lunar Easy Rider (LER) really certified moon-ready?

Is there available a formal NASA assessment of alternatives to the rover design than was chosen?

Comment: After https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_Rider came out I'm not sure NASA would have kept the name, at least.

Comment: As I understand, lunar gravity is just at the limit of where the human inner ear starts to lose its ability to maintain balance; any less and you start to get vertigo and the constant sensation of falling/floating. Add to that the clumsy Apollo suits I'm not sure I'd trust a bike on the moon even if it's a great weight savings compared to a dune buggy (as hilarious as the image is).